# Need website that has project ideas and documentation/requirements

Tags: web-applications, project, documentation, specifications, requirements

Are there any websites that have project ideas and full specifications / documentation of how to develop the project? e.g Hotel Management Systems I don't know how the hotel works. By reading doc/specs I will develop that projects. I need a project specification and documentation to develop the project